# Static IP address for local network host

Tags: networking, static-ip

How to set static IP address for host in local network?

I have a several PCs connected in network via wi-fi.

Each of this PCs have local IP address (like `192.168.1.2`).

After rebooting IP address can be different `192.168.1.2` or `192.168.1.3` and etc.

Comment: Do you want to have the host assign a static IP address to itself or do you want the DHCP server to assign the same static IP address every time this host (based on the MAC address) requests an address lease?

Answer (score 1):

we assume you want to assign ip to eth0.
you can assign ip from terminal like this :

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: `netmask 255.255.255.0` does what?

Comment: if set your subnet mask to 192.168.0.1/24